# Where can I get a list of what Crystal Reports features conflict?

Tags: crystal-reports

There are certain Crystal Reports features that cannot be combined in the same report, for example SQL command objects and server side grouping. However, as far as I can find, the built-in help doesn't seem to clearly document these conflicts. For example, checking the help page for either of those features doesn't mention that it doesn't work with the other. I want to be able to find out about these conflicts when I decide to use a new feature, not later when I go to use some other feature and the option is greyed out. Is there any place that documents these conflicts?

I am specifically working with Crystal Reports XI. Bonus points if the list of conflicts documents what range of versions each feature is available and conflicting in.

I have now also checked the release notes (release.pdf on install CD), and it does not have any answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found these anywhere, my suggestion is to create a test/dummy report, make something painfully simple that runs what your trying together.

This is of course no guarantee that is will work once you get all your real data in there.  But I've upvoted your question, cause I'd like to see those doc's myself.

Answer (score 1):

> For installation notes and details
>   regarding known issues with this
>   release, please refer to release.pdf
>   on the Crystal Reports CD.

How about the Known Issues list? Did you find anything there?

Comment: No, I hadn't. Mostly because this is more of a "how it works" type thing than a bug, at least from the view of the developers of Crystal Reports. Most of the conflicts I'm talking about have warning boxes or grey out options so you can't use them. You just won't know until after you use the feature.